# Select and replace duplicates

Tags: excel, typescript, m

I'm trying to achieve this with either Power Query or Typescript.

A column is populated with many values that are duplicated.

| Row No. | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | *01.01.2023* |
| 2 | **01.01.2023** |
| 3 | **01.01.2023** |
| 4 | *02.01.2023* |
| 5 | **01.01.2023** |
| 6 | *03.01.2023* |
| 7 | **02.01.2023** |

I don't want to remove the entire row if a cell is duplicate, but rather replace all duplicate values with a string.

| Row No. | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.01.2023 |
| 2 | cont. |
| 3 | cont. |
| 4 | 02.01.2023 |
| 5 | cont. |
| 6 | 03.01.2023 |
| 7 | cont. |

Comment: So you also want to control the order?

Comment: @SolarMike The order should stay the same (as shown in the example above). When deleting duplicates on Excel the first instance of a duplicate value is the one that remains while all other duplicate instances in the following rows are deleted. In the first table I formatted the values so that the first unique instances are in italics, while all duplicates are in bold. I edited the table so as to clarify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Power Query solution:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table23"]}[Content],

//Date typed as text to maintain format when loaded back to Excel
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Row No.", Int64.Type}, {"Date", type text}}),

//add index column for sorting
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),

//Group by date
// then replace all but first row with string
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Index", {"Date"}, {
        {"Repl Dups",(t)=>Table.ReplaceValue(
            t,
            each [Index],
            "cont.",
            (x,y,z)=> if y = List.Min(t[Index]) then x else z,
            {"Date"}
        ), type table [#"Row No."=nullable number, Date=text, Index=number]}}),

//Expand and sort the grouped table
// removing unneeded columns
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Date"}),
    #"Expanded Repl Dups" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Repl Dups", {"Row No.", "Date", "Index"}, {"Row No.", "Date", "Index"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded Repl Dups",{{"Index", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Index"})
in
    #"Removed Columns1"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your problem, You can achieve this in TypeScript using an approach similar to the following:

```
interface Row {
    RowNo: number;
    Date: string;
}

const data: Row[] = [
    { RowNo: 1, Date: '01.01.2023' },
    { RowNo: 2, Date: '01.01.2023' },
    { RowNo: 3, Date: '01.01.2023' },
    { RowNo: 4, Date: '02.01.2023' },
    { RowNo: 5, Date: '01.01.2023' },
    { RowNo: 6, Date: '03.01.2023' },
    { RowNo: 7, Date: '02.01.2023' },
];

const uniqueDates = new Set<string>();

data.forEach(row => {
    if (uniqueDates.has(row.Date)) {
        row.Date = 'cont.';
    } else {
        uniqueDates.add(row.Date);
    }
});

console.log(data);
```

You can put it in a function if you want.